# Re-arrange arrays based on given index

Tags: arrays, ruby

Here's the example:
This are just simplified version, just for you to have the idea what I am talking about.

```
current_properties = { "id" : 0, "name":1, "age": 2, "gender":3 }
new_index = { "id":0, "name":1, "gender": 2, "age": 3, "address":4 }
```

And here are the array values:

```
arr = ["1234", "John Doe", 35, "Male"]
```

Is there a way to swap values based on the given index? Those indexes that are not on the current properties, must insert a blank element.

So here's the expected output:

```
arr = ["1234", "John Doe", "Male", 35, ""]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
current_properties = {"id" => 0, "name" => 1, "age" =>  2, "gender" => 3}
new_index = {"id" => 0, "name" => 1, "gender" => 2, "age" => 3, "address" => 4}
arr = ["1234", "John Doe", 35, "Male"]

idx = new_index.map {
  |key, value| [value, key]
}.sort.map {
  |value, key| current_properties[key]
}
# => [0, 1, 3, 2, nil]  => (A kind of mapping old -> new indexes)
new_arr = (0...new_index.length).map { |i| idx[i] ? arr[idx[i]] : '' }
# => ["1234", "John Doe", "Male", 35, ""]
```

**UPDATE**: Shorter version suggested by @CarySwoveland, using [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by):

```
...
idx = new_index.sort_by(&:last).map { |key, _| current_properties[key] }        
new_arr = (0...new_index.length).map { |i| idx[i] ? arr[idx[i]] : '' }
```

Comment: Two small points: 1. You have `each.map` where `map` is sufficient. I expect you forgot to remove `each` during editing. 2. You could write `idx = new_index.map(&:reverse).sort.map...` or just `idx = new_index.sort_by(&:last).map { |key,_| current_properties[key] }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, Thank you for the comment. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we can add a default to `current_properties`:

```
current_properties.default = current_properties.size
(arr+[""]).values_at *new_index.sort_by(&:last).map {|k,_| current_properties[k]}
  #=> ["1234", "John Doe", "Male", 35, ""]
```

The steps:

After:

```
current_properties.default = current_properties.size
```

for any value that is not a key:

```
current_properties["hurray!"]
  #=> 4
```

Then:

```
a = arr + [""]
  #=> => ["1234", "John Doe", 35, "Male", ""] 

b = new_index.sort_by(&:last)
  #=> [["id", 0], ["name", 1], ["gender", 2], ["age", 3], ["address", 4]] 

c = b.map { |k,_| current_properties[k] }
  #=> [0, 1, 3, 2, 4] 

a.values_at *c
  #=> ["1234", "John Doe", "Male", 35, ""]
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using the `Enumerable` API.

```
def swap_fields(a, old, new)
  new.size.times.map { |i| old.key?(new.key(i)) ? a[old[new.key(i)]] : '' }
end
```

Or more readable.

```
def swap_fields(a, old, new)
  new.size.times.map do |i| 
    field_name = new.key(i)
    current_index = old[field_name]

    current_index ? a[current_index] : ''
  end
end
```

Comment: It's perfectly readable. Good answer, though you should state your assumption that the keys of `new` (aka `new_index`) are ordered by value. Note you can simplify  to `new.map { |_,i| ...`.